# How to save a Path & Paint object in Preferences in android

Tags: android, canvas, path, paint

I'm using `canvas.drawPath(Path path, Paint paint)` to draw a path 
which is created by user with a specified paint. 
And before closing this app ( like PhotoShop app), I want to save this 
`Path` and `Paint`. For the next time. So, user can start at their 
previous canvas(screen).

Comment: How do you populate Path with data? Which API of Path are you using?

Comment: I am not using any API. I create a my own custom class for saving Path objects.

Comment: I mean which methods of Path class have you used in order to create user defined shape. I'm asking because you could extend Path class and override those methods. And inside of them   add some kind of Command pattern object creation that are serializeble. Then you could save the list of command applied on  Path object and load it in order to recreate Path object state later. Or instead of extending you could create some kind of PathBuilder helper that will take responsibility to save, load list of steps that has been made on Path to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save a `Path` or a `Paint` object. You will need to save *the data* from which you can rebuild your `Path` and your `Paint` objects.

Whether you hold onto the data that you used when you first created those objects, or whether you try to retrieve the data from those objects via getters, is up to you. `Path`, in particular, has a "write-only" API, lacking many getters, and so you most likely will need to track how you are creating and modifying the `Path` yourself.